# White Space Between Tables SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have an ssrs report made up of multiple datasets, each one represented in its own table. I'd like to organize these nicely but when the report renders it is including whitespace between the different tables. Many answers to similar questions refer to place rectangles around the tables with this issue, but it isn't working in my case. The Consume White Space Property is set to True as well, which was a common answer.

I've included an image which also breaks down where I've placed rectangles. I have to be missing something obvious because what I'm looking to do cannot be that out of the ordinary.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your design

Comment: @AlanSchofield I was actually just able to solve it! Apparently it had to do with the tightness of the rectangles. I had the correct number, but I needed to arrange the sizes of the tables, rectangles, etc so they were all the same size. This seems to have solved it, but I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually just able to solve it! Apparently it had to do with the tightness of the rectangles. I had the correct number, but I needed to arrange the sizes of the tables, rectangles, etc so they were all the same size.